# How to create pivot table from non-numerical dataset by counting the instances from one column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot, pivot-table

I have this dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to do this:

```
df.groupby(['Phase','frames','Origin_Type']).size()
```

and

```
pd.pivot_table(india, values = ['frames', 'Phase', 'Origin_Type'], index =['frames'],
                          columns = ['Phase', 'Origin_Type'], aggfunc = sum)
```

But both didnt give me the right results. I want to transform it to this (see pic below) wherein the values should be the sum of each theme found in each 'Origin_Type' per phase.

[image]

LINK to dataset [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QzqEdf0E1ql_wXzMrQ3p3Yoi5MsPbA3n7WpiaD1Tm6Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried `aggfunc=len` or `aggfunc='count'`?

Comment: Yes, with the count one. It gave me the repeated values of 'government government government' in each cell.  The len one gave me did not sum up the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(india['Location'],[india['Phase'], india['Origin_Type']])
```